# Assert JSON formatted string equals in googletest

Tags: json, unit-testing, googletest

I have some function to test:

```
std::string getJsonResult(const SomeDataToProcessData& data);
```

The goal is to cover it with unit tests using googletest framework.
I can't compare output just as strings, because there can be different formatting for the same JSON. E.g.:

```
{"results":[], "status": 0}
```

vs.

```
{
    "results":[], 
    "status": 0
}
```

The solution for my this issue is available as additional [library](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) for JUnit, but my project is in C++.

How to do JSON formatted string assertion using gtest? Are there known implementations?

Comment: Using some json library might help...

Comment: @Jarod42 It will make dependency of your tests to specific external library. I will not be able to change external json library and check if my code still works. I will need to change the tests as well, which is wrong

Comment: @taarraas How does your code deal with the json stuff actually? You don't take my advice to clarify your question and then complain about a valid answer given?

Comment: **unclear what you're asking**
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
**too broad**
There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The function I'd like to test take some data to process, and generates results using jsoncpp library. I want to check if function generated correct results, invariant to how this json library formatted this output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have some json_parsing/formatting library available, it's simply a matter of writing your own predicate:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <string>

// simulated JSON api
struct json_object {};
extern json_object parse(std::string json);
extern std::string format_lean(json_object const& jo);

testing::AssertionResult same_json(std::string const& l, std::string const& r)
{
    auto sl = format_lean(parse(l));
    auto sr = format_lean(parse(r));
    if (sl == sr)
    {
        return testing::AssertionSuccess();
    }
    else
    {
        return testing::AssertionFailure() << "expected:\n" << sl << "\n but got:\n" << sr;
    }
}

std::string make_some_json();

TEST(xxx, yyy)
{
    auto j_expected = std::string(R"__({ foo: [] })__");
    auto j_actual = make_some_json();

    ASSERT_TRUE(same_json(j_expected, j_actual));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I was trying to implement similar to testing::StrEq functionality, but this looks simpler and with less overhead. Another issue I see, that if I will use external json library, I will lose freedom of switching to another library without changing my tests. And if I will change tests, I will be less sure that logic covered with unit tests works same.

Comment: @taarraas i think it's reasonable to statically link your json lib into your test suite. It's there as part of the fixture (like google test is), not as part of the application under test. This is not a concern. The application and test suite could have two entirely separate json libraries. All you are concerned with here is string representations.